# Precondition Failed error on HTTP request

Tags: c#

In my web project, I am using http request and response for access https payment site. But when I call `getresponse()` function, it return "Precondition failed (412)" error.

```
HttpWebRequest paymentRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://xxxxxx/authorize");
Uri uri = new Uri("https://xxxxxx/authorize");
NetworkCredential netCredential = new NetworkCredential("XXXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXX");
paymentRequest.Credentials = netCredential.GetCredential(uri, "Basic");
paymentRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;

byte[] Data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sXMLTemplate);
paymentRequest.Method = "POST";
paymentRequest.Headers.Add("MIME-Version", "1.0");
paymentRequest.Headers.Add("Request-number", "1");
paymentRequest.Headers.Add("Document-type", "Request");
paymentRequest.Headers.Add("Content-transfer-encoding", "application/xml");
paymentRequest.ContentType = "application/xml";
paymentRequest.ContentLength = Data.Length;
paymentRequest.KeepAlive = true;

Stream streamWriter = paymentRequest.GetRequestStream();
streamWriter.Write(Data, 0, Data.Length);
streamWriter.Close();



HttpWebResponse paymentResponse = (HttpWebResponse)paymentRequest.GetResponse();
Stream responseStream = paymentResponse.GetResponseStream();
reader = new XmlTextReader(responseStream);
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: As far as I can tell application/xml is not a valid content-transfer-encoding, it's a valid ContentType, but not encoding.

Comment: i have changed as paymentRequest.Headers.Add("Content-transfer-encoding", "application/PTI47"); but still it shows same error

Answer (score 0):

Please check if XML data you are POSTing validates successfully and there is no missing XML elements if XML schema is enforced

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the valid content-transfer-encodings.

- BASE64
- 8BIT
- 7BIT
- BINARY
- QUOTED-PRINTABLE

application/something is for Content-Type, not encoding.

For more info, look at the specs here:

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/5_Content-Transfer-Encoding.html

What I do Think you're after is this:

```
paymentRequest.Headers.Add("Content-type", "application/xml");
```

or simply:

```
paymentRequest.ContentType = "application/xml";
```